# Repeat a function in Javascript with .length

Tags: javascript, html

I have a long string.

```
var string = "This is a long string."
```

I also have a function to download the string to "path".

```
downloadfunction{... 'echo "'+string+'" >> '+path;}
```

How do I execute this function for every 2 letters of the string? Read somewhere about using ".length" but not sure how to implement it in this case. I also do not want to split the string into an array. The download function should help split the string to download 2 letters progressively.

I.e. I would like to download the string 2 letters at a time.

EDIT: To clarify, the string needs to be downloaded x characters at a time as the download would break if it exceeds that limit.

Comment: You can loop strings with a `for` loop and access characters by index. Then use [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) to do something every x letters.

Comment: What do you mean by "download 2 letters of the string"?

Comment: So... the string is just text inside some server side file you want to download byte by byte? Otherwise I don't understand what you mean by "download the string".

Comment: Jack, Felix, I have clarified my question. Instead of downloading that string wholesale, I need it to be downloaded every 2 characters/bytes.

Comment: I understand that. But the way you phrase it doesn't make sense. You cannot "download a string". You can download a file. Or you can access a URL and stream whatever the URL returns. And if the string is in a JavaScript source file, and you include that file via `<script>`, then the file is downloaded completely and immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that is commented on how to do this:

```
var string = 'a really really really long string \
    that I want to split by two letters at a time';

// this needs to be ceiling so that it always rounds up on odd numbers
// otherwise the last letter may be left out
var iterations = Math.ceil(string.length / 2);

for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {

    // we are iterating over half of the length but want to go two letters at a time
    var j = i*2;

    // make a new string with the first letter
    var letters = string[j]

    // this is an if statement to check if there is a second letter
    // if there is concat it to the first letter
    // otherwise the last set of an odd length would concat `undefined` to it
    if (string[j+1]) { letters += string[j+1]; }

    // call your function here passing `letters` to it
    downloadfunction{... 'echo "' + letters + '" >> '+path;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

count string length
divide by 2 round up or down what ever you like

then do a for loop of the amount after the devision.

Somethig like this

```
//Your string that is downloaded
var string = "This is a long string."

//calculate the amount of character in the string
var amount = string.length;

//divide the string by 2
var roundnr = amount/2;

for (var i=0;i<Math.round(roundnr);i++)
{ 
//do something here for every 2 characters in the string
}
```